# Error in setting protrusion factors in \microtypecontext

Tags: microtype

Using `microtype` package I'm trying to activate a specific set of `microtype` parameters for a portion of my text and I found the environment `microtypecontext` devoted to this purpose. I actually get an error when I try to specify the parameters of the features.

```
\usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand\TextIta{Cristo, risorto dai morti, che con la morte ha calpestato la morte, e a coloro che stavano nelle tombe ha donato la vita.}

\begin{document}

\begin{microtypecontext}{expansion=true, shrink = 270, stretch = 270} 

\TextIta

\end{microtypecontext}

\TextIta

\end{document}
```

With this code I get the error:

```
Package Keyval Error: shrink undefined.
```

Comment: Reading the manual, it seems that neither `shrink` nor `stretch` are valid options for `microtypecontext`.

Comment: I actually don't understand from the manual a way to specify the parameters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a context:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}

\SetExpansion[
  context=paolo,
  shrink=270,
  stretch=270,
]{encoding=*}{}

\newcommand\TextIta{Cristo, risorto dai morti, che con la morte
ha calpestato la morte, e a coloro che stavano nelle tombe ha
donato la vita.}

\begin{document}

\begin{microtypecontext}{expansion=paolo}
\TextIta
\end{microtypecontext}

\TextIta

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It was easy, but I didn't understand the manual!